# Priority_queue is sorting wrong, how to fix it?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a vector "v" and a priority queue "que" of type T which consist of two values: "ai" - a number and "ind" - the number's index in the vector. I need to sort queue by ais. I've written my comparator for this. The problem is when I push new pair of numbers in the queue it doesn't sort right. For example I have such numbers: 3, 5, 12, 1. When I push last number 1 it compares with 5 and change it place with it, then it swaps with 3. In the end the queue looks like this: 1, 3, 12, 5. Why does it happen, what is wrong?

Here is a piece of code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;
struct T {
    long long ai;
    long long ind;
};
int main() {
    long long n, m, ai;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector<long long> v;
    T st;
    auto cmp = [](const T const left,const T const right) {
        return left.ai > right.ai;
    };
    priority_queue<T, vector<T>, decltype(cmp)> que(cmp);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> ai;
        st.ai = ai;
        st.ind = i;
        v.push_back(ai);
        que.push(st);
    }
    //...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please try to create a [mcve] to show us, one that exhibits you problem and can try ourselves.

Comment: It produces the expected queue, as you can see [here](https://ideone.com/PIidd0). (I had to fix some compilation errors, so you're probably running something different. Please use copy and paste.) Please post a [mcve] with hardcoded inputs and the output method you're using for observation.

Comment: Just tested the code, and it works. As @molbdnilo said, I had to fix the comparator (you don't need two `const`s, `(const T &left, const T &right)` it's enough. Are you sure your code successfully compiles and you're not testing an older version?

Comment: You wouldn't be looking at the queue's underlying vector storage in a debugger? A priority queue isn't stored in priority order, and insertion does only O(lg n) comparisons.

Comment: I took a look in my own debugger, and the order you mention is indeed the order in the underlying vector. You can read about how priority queues are implemented on for instance [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).

Comment: Oh, sorry guys. I saw the rusult of sorting during debbuging, I watched what was in the que after it was sorted. I forgot that it's not just a vector and it has different structure.